# While in Bone Edit mode, is it possible to change individual bone's Viewport Display to different types/styles?

Tags: modeling, rigging, edit-mode, bones

Ex: Some bones would look Octahedral while others are B-Bone's. I know I can use custom shapes for different bones in Pose Mode but it seems in Edit Mode you're only allowed one type. I like Octahedral and B-Bones for different reasons and wish I could use both types at the same time, in Edit Mode.

Comment: Hello, I don't think it's possible, you either choose octahedral or b-bones. Note that even if you've segmented your bones they will act as segmented even if you've chosen the octahedral display, they don't need to be b-bonnes